# можно ли поверх google-map карты добавить блок?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```
<div class="map" id="map_canvas">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-6 adres">
                    <div class="bottom_line"></div>
                        <ul class="list-unstyled">
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/gmail.png" height="40" class="img-responsive ">
                                <a class=" location col-xs-offset-1">lorem@gmail.com</a>
                            </li><br><br><br>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/m_marker.png" height="40" class="img-responsive ">
                                <a class=" location col-xs-offset-1">122 Peacock AlyAmericus, <br    max-width: 155px>GA 317 09-5357</a>
                            </li><br><br>
                            <li>
                                <img src="images/phone.png" height="40" class="img-responsive ">
                                <a class=" location col-xs-offset-1">+465 432 571 654</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>                           
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

div.adres{
    background-color: #4576DF;
    height: 500px;
    max-width: 350px;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 70px 0px 0px 30px;
    margin-left: 15px;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        function initialize() {
            var mapOptions = {
                scrollwheel: false,
                zoom: 8,
                center: new google.maps.LatLng(32.054071,-84.189099),
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
            }

            var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);

            var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/images/map-marker1.png', new google.maps.Size(24, 35), new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
                new google.maps.Point(12, 35)); //изображение маркера


            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(32.054071,-84.189099),
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                title: 'ClickCredit'
            }); 
        }
        initialize();
    });
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: ответ: да, можно

Comment: можете мне помочь в этом ?

Comment: опишите конкретно, что у вас не получается. в теории создаёте блок с `position: absolute`, например, и располагаете его поверх вашей карты или чего угодно ещё.

Comment: вот как у меня получается:
блок (который должен быть поверх краты)
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-6 adres">
   <div class="bottom_line"></div>
    ...   
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
вот под ним блок с самой картой
<div class="map" id="map_canvas">
</div>

но он становится поверх карты, а мне нужно что бы он в самой карте был, как на макете. Присваивал верхнему блоку position="absolute", но не помогло

Answer (score 2):

```js
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.1237, -123.1137);
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 17,
    center: myLatlng,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  }
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);


  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(45.1237, -123.1137);
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    map: map,
    title: "Firefox Crop Circle"
  });

}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
.box{
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   height: 500px;
 }
.block-adres{
  position: absolute;
  width: 350px;
  height: 500px;
  left: 50px;
  top: 0;
  background-color:#4576DF;
  opacity:0.9;
  margin-left:15px;
  z-index: 5;
}
.map{
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div class="map" id="map_canvas"></div>
  <div class="block-adres">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-9 col-sm-6 adres">
          <div class="bottom_line"></div>
          <ul class="list-unstyled">
            <li>
              <img src="images/gmail.png" height="40" class="img-responsive ">
              <a class=" location col-xs-offset-1">lorem@gmail.com</a>
            </li>
            <br>
            <br>
            <br>
            <li>
              <img src="images/m_marker.png" height="40" class="img-responsive ">
              <a class=" location col-xs-offset-1">122 Peacock AlyAmericus, <br    max-width: 155px>GA 317 09-5357</a>
            </li>
            <br>
            <br>
            <li>
              <img src="images/phone.png" height="40" class="img-responsive ">
              <a class=" location col-xs-offset-1">+465 432 571 654</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
```

Comment: Привет.
Как то так, если будут вопросы пиши.
Вот http://mik4ik.ru/nasos/ - внизу карта с аналогичной задачей, если что подсмотри.