# Google Maps и ссылки на точки на карте

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, ссылки, google-api

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно реализовать "Контакты" на сайте также, как [здесь](http://www.sberleasing.ru/ru/contacts/)?

Искал такую функцию использования Google Maps, но ничего не нарыл.

Подозреваю, что всё это реализуется через JS и API карт. Но может быть есть готовый человек :) или сервис, который меня спасёт?

Comment: Оффтоп: вряд ли кто-то вам будет давать уже готовые решение. тут скорее вам напишу пример на основе которого, вы сможете работать дальше.

Comment: Само собой! Если бы кто нибудь дал пример хотябы одной такой ссылки я был бы очень благодарен

Comment: Нашел [ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/494603/%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85-google-map-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA) на похожий вопрос. Должно вам помочь.

Comment: с размещением div аки absolute проблем нет. Нужно создать ссылки внизу карты, которые будут ставить заранее заданный маркер на карту (при это выдавая мой div в качестве описания)

Answer (score 1):

есть такой ресурс https://mapbuildr.com/. там разные варианты оформления и настройки как удобно будет. все просто. потом просто в div с картой создаешь другой блок, позиционируешь его абсолютно по отношению к блоку с картой и в него вписываешь контактную информацию.

Comment: а как сделать переключение маркера гугла по ссылке как это там реализовано?

Comment: @Сергей переключение там идет через JS; попробуйте открыть код сайта и посмотреть, как реализовано у них.

Comment: я попробовал сразу) но не могу понять как все связано)